# Showing that a sequence of Neumann Series is Cauchy by selecting the right N value.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am working on the following problem:

[image]

First I define a sequence and I want to show that my sequence is in fact Cauchy, so I will need to find an $N$ value such that $$\|T^n\| + \|T^{n + 1}\| + \cdots + \|T^m\| < \epsilon$$ for all $m, n \geq N$. I am having trouble showing how for sufficiently large $N$, what I have written will be less than any $\epsilon$. I'm not sure how to pick the right $N$ value when given $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think $q = a/b$ serves any useful purpose.  Rather than defining a rational $q$, just use $c = \| T\|$,
and your proof so far shows that
$$
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\| #1 \right\|}
\norm{f_m - f_n} \le c^m + c^{m+1} + c^{m+2} + \cdots + c^n
$$
The right-hand side $c^m + c^{m+1} + c^{m+2} + \cdots + c^n$ is a positive real number.
In particular it is a pretty small real number, because
$$
c^m + c^{m+1} + c^{m+2} + \cdots + c^n
< \sum_{i=m}^\infty c^i = \frac{c^m}{1 - c}
$$
So what $N$ should you pick?  Well, you want
$$
\frac{c^m}{1 - c} < \epsilon
$$
since $m > N$ and $c < 1$, $c^m < c^N$.
Therefore it suffices to pick $N$ so that
$$
c^N < (1-c)\epsilon
$$
Since $c^N \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$, and since
$(1-c)\epsilon$ is a positive number, such an $N$ certainly exists.